# Content script - Unable to access DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, vue.js

I am trying to use a jQuery selector like

```
console.log($('input'))
```

from my **Chrome extension** and print out all the matching elements into the console.
I have inputs on my screen but they don't show up in the log currently.

My manifests file looks like this:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
  "js": [
    "./assets/jquery.min.js", 
    "./assets/vue.js", 
    "./assets/main.js",
    "./assets/lodash.js"
  ]
}]
```

What else should I be doing to be able to access these elements?

**Details:**

The Content Scripts tab of the target page is as follows:
[image: Content Scripts tab in Dev Tools]

The console output on the extension's console is:
[image]

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Can you share it in Fiddle

Comment: Assuming that code is in your content script and the content script is actually loaded (devtools - sources panel - content scripts subpanel), it's possible you have console filtering applied https://puu.sh/A1tfC/b655a08f5c.png Or maybe those elements are added AFTER the content script is injected e.g. the page is a AJAX-driven.

Comment: @GokulMaha I've added an image of the console log. It is not an error, but I think a response with no results.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think my Content Scripts are being loaded. How do I do this? Is the manifest's content_scripts section okay?

Comment: Content script must be loaded since you see the output. No elements are present (length: 0) because the page apparently adds them dynamically so you need to use MutationObserver or retry periodically using setInterval.

Comment: @wOxxOm when I right click the extension popup and go to the console, that is where I see this code.
Also, In the console of the extension, if I manually try the same command out after the DOM has fully loaded, I have the same results.

Comment: Content scripts run in web pages. The extension popup is not related to the web page, it's a separate window with its own URL. Make sure to read about the extension architecture in the documentation.

Comment: That makes it very clear @wOxxOm. I will study the architecture in the documentation first.
Since this question does not make much sense, should I delete it?